# alarm() stop randomly after some time

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I implemented a timer for a Linux user-space application using an old fashion way.

```
    int main(){
        //do some things
        signal(SIGALRM, do_things);
        alarm(1);
        while(1) {
       //other things
        }
    }

    void do_things()
    {
        tic++;//global variable
        printf("time: %d...", tic);
        if (tic%30 == 0) {
            printf("hha\n ");
            do_calculation();
        }
        alarm(1);
    }
```

It runs random times and stop print out anything, The application still alive but my timer seems gone. I have no idea where should I start to check. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Edit: Did some googling, Signal handlers are not supposed to contain "business logic" or make library calls such as printf.

All the signal handler should do is set a flag to be acted upon by non-interrupt code.

Though I still don't know what really happens to cause message disappear..

Comment: Two crucial things you need to know about signal handlers: First read about [*signal safety*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), not all functions are safe to call inside a signal handler. Secondly, a signal handler should be *quick*, it can't do long calculations.

Comment: Your signal handler function does not have the correct type, and `printf()` is not async-signal-safe, so you must not call it from a signal handler.  Additionally, use `sigaction()`, not `signal()`, to install signal handlers, as the behavior of the latter is inconsistent across implementations.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hi John, so i cannot use printf in my handler?? Is there any alternative ways? Thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hi dude, I am very curious what happen to the timer. I mean, the signal have to be sent and received since application is alive right? Do you mean my printf is somehow not working but actually the timer is not dead?

Comment: No you can't do `printf` in a signal handler. And if your `do_calculation()` is taking to much time it might also cause problems. And the next `alarm` depends on how long `do_calculation()` takes. If you want a recurring timer that is happening once every second then use e.g. [`setitimer`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) instead. And note that [`alarm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) uses the same timer as `setitimer` ***and*** `sleep`. You can't mix `alarm` and `sleep`, for example.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hi Dude thanks for your reply. Just curious, even if the calculation function takes long, but it will only messed with timer interval right? Eventually it will run alarm(1), and start to do everything again after one second?

Comment: Regarding your edit: if a signal handler either directly or indirectly calls a function that is not async-signal-safe then it thereby causes *undefined behavior*.  In that case, all bets are off -- none of the standards or specifications covering the program's behavior have anything further to say about it.  It is not useful to ask "what really happens" because even if you worked out the answer for any one particular case, it would not be useful.  *Undefined* means you cannot even rely on consistency from one run to another.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That explained everything. Thanks so much!